# Problem fetching data from API in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, next.js

Im trying to fetch some data from the popular [Morningstar](https://rapidapi.com/integraatio/api/morningstar1?endpoint=apiendpoint_58fd4b35-4d3c-4ba6-a491-8d177c8ff8a2) api. I'm using axios and also using their code example for javascript - axios.

My code looks like this:

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com/dividends',
  params: {Ticker: 'MSFT', Mic: 'XNAS'},
  headers: {
    accept: 'string',
    'x-rapidapi-key': '700c7f0abamsh61a21d67f2579cdp1097e3jsn3fa403041f99',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};
useEffect(() => {
  axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); // HERE I LOG THE DATA FROM API
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}, [])
```

And the error i get when i console logs response.data is:

https://gyazo.com/9d8a5defd87088cdeb8bc2823261d60f

Anyone that has a solution to this error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not subscribed to this API:
when running this code i got:

`{"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}`

in the network tab in the dev tool.
here is an image [image]

Comment: Okey, where exactly did in the network tab did you find this?

Comment: No problem, i found it! Weird that they had "Test endpoints" tab when you cant test it...